# How to retrieve list of all the people you follow with more following than followers?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have 6000 followers and follow 1800. But I was to reduce the amount of people I follow without the risk of losing a lot of followers. I want to reduce about a 1000. My tactic is to go one by one and see who follow more than followers they have (ie. 230 followers but follow 1000) these are less likely to stop following me.
Is there a way to do this with the API?

- Like retrieve a list of all the people I follow by the API.
- With a loop send a request to the API to retrieve the number of total followers/following
- Users with a higher follower than following count will be added to another list.
- Then unfollow from that list.

I think its doable.
But cant really think of how to start.

Comment: What's stopping you? Do you have sample code? Your algorithm sounds fine.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Im new to the instagram api, so I was wondering if anybody has already done this, so they could point me in the right direction. Or if it isnt posible then tell me to not even bother trying.